# Cannot conect to the internet using chromium or firefox

Tags: 12.10, firefox, internet

I use Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit. The issue is that I am not able to connect to the internet using browsers. The Software Center is always able to connect (the pictures of apps load). So I do not think that my wireless network card does not work. I think it is a browser related problem. Can you help me?

Comment: still having the problem? have you tried many different browsers? (seamonkey, different versions of Firefox, like 3.6, opera)

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure that you really have an internet connection. To do that open a `Terminal` and type:

```
ping -c 2 google.com
```

You should receive something like:

```
PING google.com (173.194.39.137) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bud02s03-in-f9.1e100.net (173.194.39.137): icmp_req=1 ttl=55 time=2.99 ms
64 bytes from bud02s03-in-f9.1e100.net (173.194.39.137): icmp_req=2 ttl=55 time=3.10 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.993/3.051/3.109/0.058 ms
```

If not, you have problems with your internet connection. If the connection works, then disable IPv6 as follows:
Type in `Terminal`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
```

And paste these lines at the end of the file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Save, quit, and type:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

See if the browsers work.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got this result. I read that many people have this problem in Ubuntu 12.10. Browsers do not work but somehow the internet does. So you can access internet with Software Center, terminal,etc. but not with any browser. Sometimes I got connection with my browser and sometimes it does not work. Especially after boot it does not work. I always have to wait a certain time or reconnect the network.

Comment: I see... Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but unfurtunatly this didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Took help from this [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2386012) for chrome and modified it for chromium.

```
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium/
```

This will reset chromium back to fresh install.